# Angular JS dynamically populate options for Select fields

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem that I can't figure out in Angular (I am new to Angular but not JS).

Essentially I have an HTML template that gets repeated as it loops through an array of results returned from a POST request. This all works fine, except I have a select field that will be repeated each time the loop goes round.

The template shows adverts, and each advert has a date that it was created. What I am trying to achieve and I have done this with JS and EJS before is the below:

```
            var today = moment();
            var ad_date = moment(ad.ad_date);
            var diff = today.diff(ad_date,'days');
            var lowEnd = 1;
            var highEnd = 14 - diff;
            var arr = [];
            while (lowEnd <= highEnd) {
                arr.push(lowEnd++);
            }
```

And then in the EJS I had

```
             <select class="form-control" name="offer_time">
                <% for (var d in arr) { %>
                    <option value="<%= arr[d] %>"><%= arr[d] %></option>
                <% } %>
            </select>
```

My question is how can I do the same thing in Angular?

I was thinking (although this is probably completely wrong) that I could have a function in the controller that just returns the array above and then I could do ng-repeat maybe inside the Select?

Any ideas or thoughts would be really appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Look at the documentation for `ng-options`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find everything you need in `ng-option` [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

The code to do so look like this :

```
<select ng-options="item.subItem as item.label for item in values "ng-model="selected"></select>
```

In your `ng-options`, you have the list (item here). `item.label` is what will be show in your list meanwhile item.subItem will be what will be save in your `ng-model`.

In your exemple it seems that you have a simple value, not a object. It should give something like this :

```
<select class="form-control" name="offer_time" ng-options="item for item in items" ng-model="selected"></select>
```

`Items` is your list, and `item` is what you see and what will be save. So you don't need the part with `as`

Comment: I kind of get that, what I am struggling with is $scope I think in this case. For example, I want each unique select to work out the difference in days, but if I bind the Items list to $scope won't that just mean all the selects have the same options, rather than each having it's own dynamically built options list?

Comment: So I managed to get it to populate the select using ng-init to call a function and get the array, and then using the ng-options code above. Probably not the best solution overall but in the case of this project it will suffice. Really the whole app needs to be re-written in Angular but they are not paying me for that. I'll make as accepted as the above worked perfectly once I got the data sorted! Thanks